# Error while deploying node js app?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to deploy my nodejs app on heroku. It's giving me an error like route not found and missing PFX or certificate + private key.

[image: This is the error message]

Comment: you should add a file which includes a valid certificate since you run a https server

Comment: Place the error message as text on your question, images can break over time and make it easier for people to help you with your issue.